# PropertyDefinition inconsistent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have following template that i am using in cloudformation UI to create dynamoDB table. I want to create a table with *PrimaryKey* as *ID* and *sortKey* as *Value*

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "DB Description",

  "Resources" : {
    "TableName" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties" : {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [ { 
          "AttributeName" : "ID",
          "AttributeType" : "S"
        }, { 
          "AttributeName" : "Value",
          "AttributeType" : "S"
        } ],
        "KeySchema": [
          { 
            "AttributeName": "ID", 
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ]                
      },
      "TableName": "TableName"
    }
  }
}
```

On the CF UI, I click on new stack, point to the `template` file from my local computer, give stack a name and click next. After sometime, I get error that says **Property AttributeDefinitions is inconsistent with the KeySchema of the table and the secondary indexes**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CloudFormation insists my DynamoDB creation JSON is invalid .. but I can't see how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142870/cloudformation-insists-my-dynamodb-creation-json-is-invalid-but-i-cant-see-h)

Comment: CloudFormation Linter rule to help catch this quicker with more information: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/pull/1284

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The issue is that the `Resources.Properties.AttributeDefinitions` key must *only* define columns used for indexes or keys. In other words, the keys in `Resources.Properties.AttributeDefinitions` must match the same keys defined in `Resources.Properties.KeySchema`.

AWS docs:

> AttributeDefinitions: A list of AttributeName and AttributeType objects that describe the key schema for the table and indexes.

so the resulting template would look like this:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "DB Description",

  "Resources" : {
    "TableName" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
    "Properties" : {
      "AttributeDefinitions": [ { 
        "AttributeName" : "ID",
        "AttributeType" : "S"
      } ],
      "ProvisionedThroughput":{
        "ReadCapacityUnits" : 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits" : 1
      },
      "KeySchema": [
        { 
          "AttributeName": "ID", 
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        }
       ] ,               
      "TableName": "table5"
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: If we remove the 'value' attribute from AttributeDefinitions how can we add the 'Value' column to the table ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606135/how-to-add-a-column-in-dynamodb After a research, there is no need to define all your columns when you create the table, only indexes, then you can add attributes "on the go" when inserting a new row

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385177/serverless-framework-dynamo-db-table-resource-definition-with-sort-key another answer which explains that

Comment: The question stated that `Value` should be the sort key, so it should be included in the `KeySchema`, not removed from the `AttributeDefinitions`.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct in the cause of the error, but you said you wanted the sort key to be `Value`. So you should change your CloudFormation to include that:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "DB Description",

  "Resources" : {
    "TableName" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties" : {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [ { 
          "AttributeName" : "ID",
          "AttributeType" : "S"
        }, { 
          "AttributeName" : "Value",
          "AttributeType" : "S"
        } ],
        "KeySchema": [
          { 
            "AttributeName": "ID", 
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          },
          { 
            "AttributeName": "Value", 
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
          }
        ]                
      },
      "TableName": "TableName"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In AttributeDefinitions you need to define just partition and range keys not other attributes.

number of attributes in AttributeDefinitions and KeySchema should match and should be exactly same.