# Serverless Framework Dynamo DB Table Resource Definition with Sort Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I have some code in my serverless.yml like this currently.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    uploadBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-uploads
    visitsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:custom.visitsTable}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: visitId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: comments
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: attachments
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: ph
            AttributeType: N
          - AttributeName: ch
            AttributeType: N
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: visitId
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```

My goal is to create a table with primary key userId, sort key visitId and have fields for comments, attachments, ph & ch.  When I try to `sls deploy` I get the following error.

Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

An error occurred: visitsTable - Property AttributeDefinitions is inconsistent with the KeySchema of the table and the secondary indexes.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit: Another attempt I tried**

```
resources:
  Resources:
    uploadBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-uploads
    visitsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:custom.visitsTable}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: visitId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: visitId
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```

Comment: You have mentioned visitid as range key(sort). But in your YAML configuration it's mentioned as Hash key. `- AttributeName: visitId
            KeyType: RANGE`

Comment: I was wondering if I should put range but wasn't sure if that was what a 'sort' was.

Comment: I've tried putting range but same error. (and I put it with all caps, RANGE), like in your example, any other ideas?

Comment: You are trying to create a Table. So remove the attributes other than Key Schema and Indexes. From AWS DOCS it's clear that, AttributeDefinitions is an array of attributes that describe the key schema for the table and indexes. For more http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html#DDB-CreateTable-request-AttributeDefinitions

Comment: Interesting, so what would that look like then? do I still need 2 Keyschema values?

Comment: updated my code to reflect setting it up this way, does it look correct? I think it worked this time possibly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

AWS DynamoDb is a NO-SQL type database and no need to define all the keys during the Table creation. Also from the AWS documentation it's clear that in Attribute Definition you have to specify the Key schema and indexes.

> An array of attributes that describe the key schema for the table and indexes.

Please edit your code as below

```
resources:
  Resources:
    uploadBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-uploads
    visitsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:custom.visitsTable}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: visitId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: visitId
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```

For More [CreateTable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html#DDB-CreateTable-request-AttributeDefinitions)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I didn't realize I didn't need the other info.

Comment: Do you know by chance how to delete only the resources created with serverless? For example, I want to delete the table because lets say I changed it, but I don't want the entire stack to drop because the lambda api gateway endpoints will change.  Curious if you know how to do this.

Comment: You can use the `DeletionPolicy: "Retain"` in your YAML script. Modify the YAML file and add the above property in your Lambda and API gateway definitions. What it will do is when you delete the stack the DynamoDB Table will be deleted and the other resources are retained.

Comment: I'm a bit confused how to use this with serverless, can you show me an example, I created another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385994/destroy-resources-created-via-serverless-without-destroying-lambda-endpoints

Comment: In the question I show my entire serverless.yml file to help.