# Updating multiple records in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, batch-processing

How can i update multiple records in DynamoDB in single query?
I have a csv file as an input based on the csv file I have to update multiple records(only one attribute) in the DB.
Is there any API available for this?
or This can be done using batch processing(Spring-batch)?

Answer (score 6):

DynamoDB doesn't have `batchUpdate` API directly. It does have `batch get item` and `batch write item` API.

However, you can use `batchWriteItem` API to update the item.

1) Use the below `BatchWriteItemSpec` class to construct the request

[BatchWriteItemSpec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/spec/BatchWriteItemSpec.html)

2) Use the below `TableWriteItems` class to construct the item that need to be updated

[TableWriteItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/TableWriteItems.html)

3) Use the below `addItemToPut` method (or `withItemsToPut`) to add the new attribute

[addItemToPut](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/TableWriteItems.html#addItemToPut-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item-)

The `batchWriteItem` API creates a new item if the item (i.e. partition key) is not available. If the partition key is available, it will update the existing item. Your use case falls under this category.

**Code Sample:-**

**files** - is the the table name

**fileName** - is the partition key

**transcriptionnew** - Adding the new attribute (or can update the existing attribute value as well)

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamoDBClient);

            Item itemUpdate1 = new Item();

            itemUpdate1.withKeyComponent("fileName", "file1")
                    .withString("transcriptionnew", "new value");

            Item itemUpdate2 = new Item();

            itemUpdate2.withKeyComponent("fileName", "file2")
                    .withString("transcriptionnew", "new value");

            TableWriteItems tableWriteItems = new TableWriteItems("files").withItemsToPut(itemUpdate1, itemUpdate2);

            BatchWriteItemSpec batchWriteItemSpec = new BatchWriteItemSpec().withTableWriteItems(tableWriteItems);

            BatchWriteItemOutcome batchWriteItemOutCome = dynamoDB.batchWriteItem(batchWriteItemSpec);

            if (batchWriteItemOutCome.getUnprocessedItems().isEmpty()) {
                //All items are processed
                return true;
            }
```